# Parse Server Live query did receive new objects when my app is close?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, websocket, parse-server

I have a question about livequery:

If I implement live query in my iOS client, I receive new object when my app is close ? (Like push notifications)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer is NO. parse live query is based on the WebSocket protocol so an active connection must be available in order to receive the events and app which are not in foreground cannot have an active connection to WebSocket. If your app will be in the background it will take about 1-2 minutes until the WebSocket connection will automatically be closed by the OS and this is done to save resources. So you can do what i did:

1. When the app is in foreground and active use LiveQuery as normal and handle events inside the app
2. When your app is in background or closed use push notifications to notify the user about important changes.

You can know if a user is online/offline by storing a flag of isOnline under the User object and when the app is active update this flag to true and when it is not active update this flag to false.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, that was I thinking but I want to be sure, thanks a lot for your answer :)

Comment: No problem. Glad that i was helpful